# Azure Sql Server VPN connection

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, azure, vpn

I saw a couple of questions already submitted 1 or 2 year ago, without a clear answer. I'd like to know if I can connect my private Network, or whatelse to an Azure Sql Server.

[Point-to-Site VPN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-howto-point-to-site-resource-manager-port)

I'd like to attach a VNET to my Azure Sql Server, Set up a Network Security Group and VPN GATEWAY and connect (with enterprise certificate or self signed) to my DB's directly from Visual Studio or Microsoft Sql Management studio.

Comment: You may want to vote for this feature here https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217321-sql-database/suggestions/5537689-allow-sql-database-to-join-virtual-network-vpn

Answer (score 1):

I've solved with a Preview Solution and connected from the inside virtual network to Sql Server on port 1433.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-private-endpoint-overview

Next step: Certification Management of the VPN'S client.

Other Solution in Preview also....

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/openvpn-azure-ad-client